# Remove certain elements from a sequence of dates in R

Tags: r, seq, as.date

I am trying to create a sequence of dates in R without certain days. I use the following code to create the sequence:

```
date_range<- seq(as.Date("2018-1-1"),as.Date("2018-12-31"), by='days')
```

but I don't want to remove certain days, for example '2018-10-16' and '2018-9-12'. I am not sure how to do this. 
I am new to R and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a vector of dates that you want to remove and then use `%in%`

```
remove_dates <- as.Date(c('2018-10-16', '2018-9-12'))
all_dates <- seq(as.Date("2018-1-1"),as.Date("2018-12-31"), by='days')
all_dates[!all_dates %in% remove_dates]
```

Or with `setdiff`

```
as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, remove_dates))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `between`

```
library(dplyr)
date_range[!between(date_range,  as.Date('2018-9-12'), as.Date('2018-10-16'))]
```

If it it only these dates, then use

```
as.Date(setdiff(date_range, c("2018-09-12", "2018-10-16")), origin = '1970-01-01')
```